# Very simple UDP server/client on Android wont work

Tags: java, android, networking, udp

I'm trying to do a very simple client on android to send an UDP message to a server on Android.

Here's my simple UDP client:

```
public class MyUDPClient {
    private static String TAG = "MyUDPClient";
    private DatagramSocket udpSocket;
    private InetAddress serverAddress;
    private int port;
    private Scanner scanner;

    public MyUDPClient(String destinationAddr, int port) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException {
        this.serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(destinationAddr);
        this.port = port;
        udpSocket = new DatagramSocket(this.port);
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void send(String message) throws IOException {
        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(
                message.getBytes(), message.getBytes().length, serverAddress, port);
        Log.d(TAG, "udp client send: " + message + " to serverAddress " + serverAddress);
        this.udpSocket.send(p);
    }

    public void connect() {
        Log.d(TAG, "UDP connection to port " + port);
    }
}
```

And here's my simple UDP server:

```
public class MyUDPServer  {
    private String TAG = "MyUDPServer";
    private int port;
    private DatagramSocket udpSocket;
    OnMessageCallback onMessageCallback;

    public MyUDPServer(int port) throws SocketException {
        this.udpSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        this.port = port;
    }


    public interface OnMessageCallback {
        public void on(String message);
    }

    private void listen() throws Exception {
        Log.d(TAG, "listening UDP server on port " + port);
        String msg;

        while (true) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

            // blocks until a packet is received
            udpSocket.receive(packet);
            msg = new String(packet.getData()).trim();
            Log.d(TAG, "message received; " + msg);
            onMessageCallback.on(msg);
        }
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        listen();
    }

    public void setMessageCallback(OnMessageCallback onMessageCallback) {
        this.onMessageCallback = onMessageCallback;
    }

}
```

The problem is that the server never receives any messages. I start the client like this:

```
MyUDPClient myUDPClient = new MyUDPClient("192.168.1.6", 8887);
```

Since it's on an emulator, I try to filter the IP `192.168.1.6` and even though I call `myUDPClient.send("message")`, on WireShark I receive nothing, which indicates that the message is not even leaving the computer where the emulator tuns.

What am I doing wrong?

I've created a WebSocket client/server on Android and it worked fine.

I have these 2 permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: The emulator is not on the same network as your Android app phone. So unreachable.

Comment: Further you did not tell if the client or server was running on an emulator. Not that it matters..

Comment: @blackapps the client is on the emulator. But the websocket worked in the emulator and reached a phone in the same network

Comment: @blackapps I just used a phone instead of an emulator and the same problem happens, I see nothing on the server, which is in the same network

Comment: You used two phones now? Is that what you said? You did not tell where your server runs in your last comment.

Comment: @blackapps first test: client on emulator, server on phone 192.168.1.6. Second test: client on phone, server on phone 192.168.1.6. If the problem was that the phone was unreachable then I'd still see the output in Wireshark in the first test with emulator

Comment: How do you start the server? And why is the client sending to its own port number instead of the server's?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I start the server simply as `myServer = new MyUDPServer(port);`

Comment: @MarquisofLorne the client uses the same port as the server

Comment: Not if they're both in the same host it doesn't, not with this code. Duplicate of [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I was gatting `NetworkOnMainThreadException` but it was being logged to another part of the logcat that I wasn't filtering for.

Doing the `myudpClient.send("myMessage")` from a separate thread solved the problem. That's why I couldn't even see the output on Wireshark, it wasn't even sending.

Answer (score 0):

In your MyUDPClient-class simply change to avoid a "double" binding that causes the exception:

```
public MyUDPClient(String destinationAddr, int port) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException {
  super();
  this.serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(destinationAddr);
  this.port = port;
  udpSocket = new DatagramSocket(this.port);
  scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
}
```

to

```
public MyUDPClient(String destinationAddr, int port) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException {
  super();
  this.serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(destinationAddr);
  this.port = port;
  udpSocket = new DatagramSocket();
  //udpSocket = new DatagramSocket(this.port);
  scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
}
```

Comment: still wont work. Also I see no output in wireshark when I filter for UDP